# How to find all variations (accented, etc) of a searched string in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, non-ascii-characters, turkish, utf8mb4

I have a big `MySQL`, `InnoDB` table which holds data in `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. I have records from almost every languages those are based on latin alphabet. I am easily able to search words with accented characters and find results with different variations (accented/not-accented), but there is a problem with the Turkish language. A basic `LIKE` keyword does not work in the `SQL` line when you specify a word that includes a big `I` letter. I expect to see all words those include the lower case version of that letter too (which is dotless `i`).

So, `I`is `i` in English, but it is **dotless** `i` in Turkish. (`ı`)

`SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'SIR'` does not bring the word `sır` word. It only brings `sir` word but they both exist in the same table.

Have you ever had any problem like this? How to solve it with `SQL`?

**update:**
`SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'SIR'` **`COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci`** returns `sır` but not `sir`. Even though this could solve some of the problems, unfortunately, it takes 23 seconds to return from this query instead of 0.00003 seconds (without `COLLATE` keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Index or scan?**

In your example, I assume `word` was indexed?  And the table is rather large?  In that case, an index is very powerful for finding the row(s) that match *for the specified collation*.  Any other collation (your case with `COLLATE ...`) requires ignoring the index and scanning the *entire* table (slow).

Using `REGEXP` will *also* require a full table scan.
Doing `REPLACE(...)` on the fly will require a full table scan.

So, given that there are "too many" rows to allow for a full table scan, there is no simple way to search for `sır` or `sir` for arbitrary collations.  Let's look for another way...

First, let's look at some **collation cases**.

In most utf8 collations, including utf8_unicode_ci, I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ
In utf8_turkish_ci, I=ı, but they come before i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ (and hence, explains part of your problem).
Most other utf8 collations treat ı as coming between i and j.
utf8_general_ci is slightly different:  I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ=ı
utf8_icelandic_ci treats some accented i's as a different letter:  I=i=Ì=Î=Ï=ì=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ, but Í=Í=í=í fall between I and J.  That one also sorts these after Z:  Ä=Æ=ä=æ  Ö=Ø=ö=ø  Å=å

**See** my [*Reference*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html)

Another problem:  Accented letters *can* be presented as two utf8 characters - the letter, then a "non-spacing mark"

So, what to do??

**Plan A**:  Build your own collation.  This takes some work, but is not impossible.  This would be optimal, giving you the best performance.  As we will see below, utf8_unicode_520_ci comes very close, and could be a starting point.

**Plan B**:  Add another column in your table; let's call it `wordx`.  It would have `word`, but will tall accents stripped.  Then index `wordx` instead of `word`.  So the row with word='sır' would have wordx='sir'.

**Plan C**:  Using the equivalences discussed above, pick one type if "I" from each group for the collation defined in the table, then use `utf8_unicode_520_ci` with `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE word = 'sir' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE word = 'sır' )
```

This should catch all flavors of `i`.

**Oops**, what about words with multiple different accentable letters?  At first glance, maybe it is not a problem -- all `a` collate equal in utf8_unicode_520_ci.  Glancing through the rest of the letters, I don't see anything other than `ı` giving a problem.

Here are the interesting **equivalences for `utf8_unicode_520_ci`**:

```
A=a=ª=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae=Æ=æ  az  B=b  C=c=Ç=ç=Č=č  ch  cz
D=d=Ð=ð=Ď=ď  dz  E=e=È=É=É=Ê=Ë=è=é=é=ê=ë=Ē=ē=Ĕ=ĕ=Ė=ė=Ę=ę=Ě=ě  F=f  fz  ƒ
G=g=Ğ=ğ=Ģ=ģ  gz  H=h  hz  I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ  ij=ĳ  iz  ı  J=j
K=k=Ķ=ķ  L=l=Ĺ=ĺ=Ļ=ļ=Ł=ł  lj=Ǉ=ǈ=ǉ  ll  lz  M=m  N=n=Ñ=ñ=Ń=ń=Ņ=ņ=Ň=ň  nz
O=o=º=Ò=Ó=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=Ø=ò=ó=ó=ô=õ=ö=ø  oe=Œ=œ  oz  P=p  Q=q  R=r=Ř=ř  S=s=Ş=ş=Š=Š=š=š
sh  ss=ß  sz  T=t=Ť=ť  TM=tm=™  tz  U=u=Ù=Ú=Ú=Û=Ü=ù=ú=ú=û=ü=Ū=ū=Ů=ů=Ų=ų  ue  uz  V=v
W=w  X=x  Y=y=Ý=Ý=ý=ý=ÿ=Ÿ  yz  Z=z=Ž=Ž=ž=ž  zh  zz  Þ=þ  µ
```

If you consider `ƒ` to be an accented letter, then you might want to deal with it, too.

Your question is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known tricky problem for unicode text processing in general. All you can do is to use `OR` for words with different forms of i or use a regular expression pattern.

Comment: That's a problem :/ because I use subqueries and therefore I cannot supply various forms. The only thing I can do is join a table twice with `REPLACE(word,'I','ı')` form which makes it more complex. I will mark your answer as 'the' answer, in a few days. Thank you :|